# Convert doubles quotes encoded json with single quotes into proper json format in python

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I have following Data

```
data = "{'name': 'python'}"
```

I need to convert this into proper json format

```
data = {"name":"python"}
```

How can I achieve this in python 3 ?

Comment: @metmirr `eval` should already return a dictionary here.

Comment: @dirn yes you are right it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using regex:

```
import re
test = "{'name': 'python'}"
print(re.sub("'(?=([\w]+|[:,\\s}]+))", "\"", test))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

`import json
d = json.loads(data)`

Comment: it gives error
**json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)**

Comment: JSON strings must always be enclosed in double quotes. Change `data` to  '{"name":"python"}'  and try again, you should be able to index your `data` with `d["name"]`